# background image on half the page - text on the other half

Tags: html, css, image, background, background-image

Is it possible to have a background image on half the page and text on the other half (vertically)?  I've tried to accomplish this, but I cant get the background image to stay on the left side of the page and the text to stay on the right?  Can anyone help me with any solutions?

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/egLf2b9p/

```css
#half-text-half-image {
  display : flex;
  align-items : center;
}
.half-width-img, .half-width-text {
  width: 50%;
}
.half-width-text {
  padding: 0 0px;
    text-align: justify;
}
.half-width-img {
      width:50%;
    min-height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    height:auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="half-text-half-image">
<div class="half-width-img" style="background-image: url('http://www.arfhamptons.org/wp-content/gallery/garden-tour-2016/IMG_2680.jpg');"></div><div class="half-width-text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single `div`, with left padding `50%`, and background image with background size of `50%`:

```css
#half-text-half-image {
  padding: 0 0 0 50%;
  background-image: url('http://www.arfhamptons.org/wp-content/gallery/garden-tour-2016/IMG_2680.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="half-text-half-image">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
  sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus
  elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum.
  Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit
  vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh.
  Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I used a flexbox to separate the screen.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200">
  </div>
  <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you wanted:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#half-text-half-image { position: relative; }
.half-width-img, .half-width-text { width: 50%; }
.half-width-text {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0px;
  text-align: justify;
  left: 50%;
}
.half-width-img {
  min-height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  height:auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want moderate your code. try this

```css
#half-text-half-image {
  display : flex;
}
.half-width-img, .half-width-text {
  width: 50%;
}
.half-width-text {
  padding: 0 0px;
  text-align: justify;
}
.half-width-img {
    min-height:100%;  
    height:auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="half-text-half-image">
<div class="half-width-img" style="background-image: url('http://www.arfhamptons.org/wp-content/gallery/garden-tour-2016/IMG_2680.jpg');"></div><div class="half-width-text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
</div>
</div>
```